# one commit missing after rebasing

Tags: git

Below is the initial commit graph:
[image]

and I want to rebase the inspiration branch on v0.1-release as

```
git rebase v0.1-release
```

then I got 
[image]

I'm really confused, why the commit("Advanced practice technique") is not even in the `inspiration` branch?

isn't that rebasing is to apply the two commits(on inspiration) onto the `v0.1-release` branch? how come only one left?

Comment: Is it possible that all of the changes in the the `Advanced practice technique` commit were already made in other commits on the `v0.1-release` branch?

Answer (score 1):

`Advanced practice technique.` is already in `v0.1-release`.

[git-rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> Note that any commits in HEAD which introduce the same textual changes
>   as a commit in HEAD..<upstream> are omitted (i.e., a patch already
>   accepted upstream with a different commit message or timestamp will be
>   skipped).

You also have this commit in `master`, what's more, it's even reverted in `master`. Looks like things got out of control.

Also, the `instpiration` branch is pushed.

[Pro Git - 3.6 Git Branching - Rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

> If you rebase commits that have already been pushed publicly, and
>   people may have based work on those commits, then you may be in for
>   some frustrating trouble and the scorn of your teammates.